# DRY way to check parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two similiar functions that both require the same parameter checks

```
function doThis(foo, bar) {
    if (foo.length === 0) foo = 'foo';
    if (bar.length === 0) bar = 'bar';

    foo = encodeURI(foo);
    bar = encodeURI(bar);

    // ... some other checks and enforcements...

    // Output as alert
    alert(foo + bar);
}

function doThat(foo, bar) {
    if (foo.length === 0) foo = 'foo';
    if (bar.length === 0) bar = 'bar';

    foo = encodeURI(foo);
    bar = encodeURI(bar);

    // ... some other checks and enforcements...

    // Output on console
    console.log(foo + bar);
}
```

What is a proper way to dry this up? I came up with this:

```
function paramsCheck(foo, bar) {
    if (foo.length === 0) foo = 'foo';
    if (bar.length === 0) bar = 'bar';

    foo = encodeURI(foo);
    bar = encodeURI(bar);

    // maybe some other checks and enforcements...

    return { foo: foo, bar: bar };
}

function doThis(foo, bar) {
    var params = paramsCheck(foo, bar);

    // Output
    alert(params.foo + params.bar);
}

function doThat(foo, bar) {
    var params = paramsCheck(foo, bar);

    // Output
    console.log(params.foo + params.bar);
}
```

But I'm not really happy with it. I would rather like pass the parameters as references to `paramsCheck()`, so I can directly modify them instead of returning a new object.

Comment: No, this is the correct and most readable way IMO.

Comment: This way is fine and there is nothing better (with the possible exception of merging all parameters in one object, in which case you can pass it to a function for massaging).

Comment: I would only suggest to extract setting default value to an util function. Gruss aus Winterthur. :)

Comment: @Jon That's what I've done in the end. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Zuberbühler: Einen festlichen Gruss zurück ;-) (Bin gerade in Zürich)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
function doThis(foo, bar) {
    foo = clean(foo, 'foo');
    bar = clean(bar, 'bar');

    // ... some other checks and enforcements...

    // Output as alert
    alert(foo + bar);
}

function clean(value, defaultValue){
    if (value.length === 0) value = defaultValue;
    return encodeURI(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That could work, although with what you've given I would suggest something like this:

```
function paramsCheck(params) {
    var l = params.length, i;
    for( i in params) if( params.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        params[i] = encodeURI(params[i] === 0 ? i : params[i]);
    }
}
function doThis(foo,bar) {
    var params = {foo:foo,bar:bar};
    paramsCheck(params);
    // now do stuff
}
```

This solution is more flexible because it doesn't make assumptions about the input, so you can very easily add a third parameter.

Comment: what about the default value?

Comment: Well, that's what the ` ? i` part is for - the keys are the default values in the examples, so I rolled with it.